# There is a dialog message each time i start my computer

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7

A message dialog occurs when i start my computer

[image]

as it is showing this so i have to reinstall tomcat again and again to do practice of Servlet 
programs can anybody help me.
why this is coming?how to tackle this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem occurs due to the Tomcat service not having administrator privilege to start on startup of your system.

To mark an application to always run as an administrator, do the following:

1. On the Start menu, locate the program that you want to always run as an administrator.
2. Right-click the application’s shortcut, and then click Properties.
3. In the Properties dialog box, click the Compatibility tab.
4. Do one of the following:

   - To apply the setting to the currently logged-on user, select the Run This Program As An Administrator check box, and then click OK.
   - To apply the setting to all users on the computer and regardless of which shortcut is used to start the application, click Change Setting For All Users to display the Properties dialog box for the application’s .exe file, select the Run This Program As An Administrator check box, and then click OK twice.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks its working now i have changed settings as you described